# java reactor filterAndMap?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I want to use [reactor](http://projectreactor.io/) achieve:

```
for (val worker : getWorkers(request)) {
    val response = worker.tryDo(work);
    if (response != null) {
        return response;
    }
}
return null;
```

`getWorkers` can transfer to return `Flux<Worker>`, `tryDo` can also return a mono.

The key is I want exactly one or zero Response and only try the next if the current `worker.tryDo` fails.

Which operator do I need? I cannot find an answer in the [document](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#which.values).

Comment: nulls are not permitted in reactive streams, so you'll have to work around that. the tryWork method suspiscously sounds like it could block, which is not a good fit either for a reactive map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the gitter, which come from @OlegDokuka:

```
Mono.fromDirect(workersFlux.concatMap(worker -> 
    Mono.justOrEmpty(worker.tryDo(work))).take(1))
```

**Update:**

Thanks for @Simon Baslé: Use `singleOrEmpty` instead of `fromDirect`.

```
workersFlux.concatMap(worker -> Mono.justOrEmpty(worker.tryDo(work))).take(1).singleOrEmpty()
```

Comment: prefer avoiding `fromDirect` which is less safe than chaining a `singleOrEmpty()`. also missing a parenthesis, so this should be `workersFlux.concatMap(worker -> 
    Mono.justOrEmpty(worker.tryDo(work))).take(1).singleOrEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you can rework tryWork to return a Mono that is empty when no work instead of returning null, you could use `getWorkers(request).flatMap(worker -> worker.tryDo(work), 1).next()`

the `1` parameter to `flatMap` instruct it to only consider workers 1 by 1.
workers that return an empty mono are effectively not influencing the output of flatMap. 
`Flux.next()` converts to `Mono` by discarding elements past the first one and cancelling the source.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't clarify my question: I want exactly one or zero Response and only try the next if the current
worker.tryDo fails.